# When were arrows first used to visualise vectors?

Tags: mathematics, physics

I guess the use of arrows to visualise vectors came before the general notion of vectors, so a more precise question is: when where arrows first used to visualise physical (or mathematical) quantities which are nowadays considered to be vectors? For instance: when where arrows first used to visualise forces, velocities, tuples of numbers etc.? And were there ever competing ways to visualise vectors?

Comment: Good question. Neither pseudo-Aristotle in Mechanics, nor Newton in *Principia* used arrows where we would. Possibly, it originated with Monge's technical drawing and then spread in 19th century. I'd consult Booker's History of Engineering Drawing, but I do not have access to it.